# Regular Expression in JavaScript giving an uncaught type error

Tags: javascript, regex

I am developing an application and want to be able to grab only the resource from the URL so I have written a regular expression, but it doesn't seem to be working and I get an uncaught type error. Can anyone help with this?

```
var link = document.location;

var res = link.match(/\/.*php/g);
```

Comment: Can you show us the *exact* error you get?

Comment: Also, [`document.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.location) isn't a string.  It's a [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object.

Comment: @RocketHazmat it's in the Chrome browser "uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.location` is not a string, but a [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object with properties describing the individual components of the URL.  It therefore has no `match` method.

Try using `document.location.pathname` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `link` is not a string, so it doesn't have the `match()` property.

try:

```
var link = document.location.toString();
var res = link.match(/\/.*php/g);
```